# Let a group $G$ acts transitively on sets $X$ and $Y$, where $1 < |X| < |Y| = p$ and $p$ is prime. Show that $G$ is not simple.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I am currently studying for an algebra qualifying exam and am stuck on how to even start this problem.

Suppose that a group $G$ acts transitively on sets $X$ and $Y$, where $1 < |X| < |Y| = p$ and $p$ is prime. Show that $G$ is not simple.

I found this problem: [Let group $G$ acts transitively on finite sets $\Omega$ and $\Psi$, with $1<|\Omega|<|\Psi|$. If $G$ is simple, show that $|\Psi|$ cannot be prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322077/422612), which asks you to show that if $G$ is simple, then $|Y|$ is not prime. I've tried reading through it to see if I could gain some insight to help with this problem, but I'm still stuck.

I tried a proof by contradiction (assume $G$ is simple) and found that the only normal subgroup of $G$ must be the trivial group, or else if it were $G$, then $G$ wouldn't act transitively on $X$ and $Y$. Using the page I linked, you can also show that $G$ acts faithfully on $X$ and $Y$. Then I got stuck and have no idea how to proceed.

Another approach is that we know $p = \frac{|G|}{|G_Y|}$ and $|X| = \frac{|G|}{|G_X|} < p$. The page I linked stated that "if $p$ is prime then clearly $p$ cannot be the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, i.e., we must have another prime $q<p$ with $q \mid |G|$. I don't understand this reasoning, but I think it may help with finding a non-trivial normal subgroup, since if $q \mid |G|$, then we have a subgroup of order $q$.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: If $G$ is infinite then the actions will give you proper normal subgroups. So assume $G$ is finite. You know that $p$ divides the order of $G$. Now consider the induced map from $G$ to $S_X$ given by the action of $G$ on $X$ and think about the kernel of that homomorphism. Can it be the whole group? Can it be trivial?

Comment: When you write "I don't understand this reasoning", do you mean you don't understand why your quoted text is true, or you don't understand how it's used?  If the former, just note that $|X|$ divides $|G|$ and $1 < |X| < p$, so any prime divisor of $|X|$ is smaller than $p$ and must also divide $|G|$.

Comment: I may miss something…  It seems to me that the link you refer to is exactly what you’re looking to prove.